How do I add access scopes to "trusted applications for identity propagation" in the AWS IAM Identity Center?
In one of my AWS managed applications (in the AWS Identity Center) I want to increase the 3 scopes for these applications:

To all 5 scopes related to Q Business:

It is straight-forward to edit for the customer-managed application as there's an edit button (as shown in the second picture) but not for the AWS-managed ones.
I have already created a role that the user assumes to run all Q business commands. When this role is assumed however, the user seems to only have read access (can list applications, etc), but still cannot write or create a new conversation.
When I try to run the ChatSync command in the cli, I receive the error:
"An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the ChatSync operation: User is not authorized for this service call."
Therefore, I think the access scopes shown in the first picture are the limiting factor. I have also double-checked the trust relationships and policies 100 times.
